# How to remove the clip of a region in html 5 canvas

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas

I am working with `clip()` in canvas.

I have made a region to `clip()`, as specified below

```
this.svgRenderer.ctx.rect(positionX, positionY, Width, Height);
this.svgRenderer.ctx.clip();
```

After few drawing on the same canvas, I am trying to remove the clip for that region by using `save()` and `restore()`.

But I am making mistakes and can't get that.
So suggest any other way to remove the clip for the specified region without using `save()` and `restore()`

Comment: Could you show code with what you're trying to do with save() and restore()?

Answer (score 36):

`.clip` is a permanent context state change.

It can only be removed by wrapping it in `.save` and `.restore`.

```js
ctx.save();
ctx.clip(); // assuming the clipping path was already declared
// draw whatever needs to be clipped
ctx.restore(); // reset the clipping region
               // (and any other attributes that have been modified since .save())
```

Changing the canvas element width or calling [`.reset()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/reset) will clear the context state (and remove clipping) but will also erase the existing drawings.